# Getting 2 seperate time values using regex in Java

Tags: java

So far I have successfully got the time values from a text file. '09:00 19:00'. This is what the time values are set out like in the text file. Is there any way to get it so these 2 values are seperate. Like "Start time - 09:00" and "End time - 19:00". I have been able to get the values '09:00 19:00' from the text file. It is just the ability to seperate them that I cannot find

```
String available = null;
        Boolean isAvail;
        Date day = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        String token1 = "";

        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Jordanstown\\NetBeans Projects\\COM373\\Availabilty Update File.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

        List<String> availability = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (inFile1.hasNext()) 
            {
                token1 = inFile1.next();
                availability.add(token1);
                }
        inFile1.close();


    String[] availabilityArray = availability.toArray(new String[0]);

    String searchArray = simpleDateformat.format(day);
    for (String curVal : availabilityArray)
    {
        if (curVal.contains(searchArray))
        {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(curVal);
            if (matcher.find())
            {
                //System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                available = matcher.group(1);

            }
        }
    }
    //I would want to have these 2 strings being the 2 times from the text file
    String timeStart = "14:00";
    String timeEnd = "20:00";

    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(timeStart);
    LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse(timeEnd);
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
    if (now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(stop)) 
    {
        isAvail = true;
        System.out.println(isAvail);
    }else{
        isAvail=false;
        System.out.println(isAvail);
    }
```

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) the string on the separating space.

```
String input = "09:00 19:00";
String[] values = input.split(" ");
String startTime = values[0];
String endTime = values[1];
System.out.println(startTime); // prints: 09:00
System.out.println(endTime);   // prints: 19:00
```

You can also use [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

```
String input = "09:00 19:00";
int idx = input.indexOf(' ');
String startTime = input.substring(0, idx);
String endTime = input.substring(idx + 1);
System.out.println(startTime); // prints: 09:00
System.out.println(endTime);   // prints: 19:00
```

These are all common methods on the `String` class, and you should have been able to find them yourself, if you just **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).